# Search criterion lies between two row values: Identify lower and higher value

Tags: excel

I am working the first time with Excel and looking for a intuitively easy command but I cant find anything. I have 5 different values in column 1 and respective values in column 2, that represent the degree of modernisation in column A (in points) and the remaining useful life of real estates in column B (in years). Since the achieved points of column A can lie between the rows, I want to identify the lower and higher value of the achieved points to calculate the weighted average.

```
Degree of modernisation     Remaining useful life
          1                        22
          4                        27
          8                        34
          13                       43
          18                       52
```

More precisely, in my case the Degree of modernisation is 11 and lies between 8 and 13. Consequently, the lower value is 8 and the next higher value is 13. Which commands can you recommend to identify those values based on my example with search number 11?

Comment: When the degree of modernization is `11` what value should Excel return? - `34` or `43`? or do you have any method to compute ?

Comment: Since I have varying degress of modernisation (11 is just an example) I primarily need commands to identify the next higher/lower values. After identification, I compute the weighting factors based on the range to the search criterion and then calculate the final value by weighting 34 and 43, respectively. E.g. 8 is 3 points away from 11 and 13 is 2 points away, based on that the value for 13 should be weighted higher (0,6) and 8 lower (0,4) resulting in: 34 * 0,4 + 43 * 0,6 = 39,4 and rounded 39.

Comment: If you are trying to `interpolate` values (and not weighing) then [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/214096/method-to-calculate-interpolation-step-value-in-excel) has a solution for you

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but the framework of real estates (in this case) clearly rejects interpolation, so that I wanted to try it with weighing!

Comment: Got it... but i could not understand how you got 0.6 for 13 and 0.4 for 34

Comment: First of all my weights are based on the range between both higher and lower values. 13-8 = 5. Keeping in mind the individual distances of 8 and 13 to the search criterion 11, I came up with 0,6 for 43 (13 ist nearer to 11) and 0,4 for 34 (8 is 3 "units" away from 11 and thus lower weighted). The weighting sheme might be suboptimal, the main focus lies on the identification of higher and lower values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution. I split it into the single steps so it should be self-explaining.

```
   |  A                        B     C
---+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |
 2 |  1                       22    
 3 |  4                       27    
 4 |  8                       34    
 5 | 13                       43    
 6 | 18                       52    
 7 |    
 8 | Inspected number         11    
 9 | Nearest lower - index     3    =MATCH(B8,$A$2:$A$6, TRUE)
10 | Nearest higher - index    4    =B9+1
11 | Nearest lower - key       8    =INDEX($A$2:$A$6, B9)
12 | Nearest higher - key     13    =INDEX($A$2:$A$6, B10)
13 | Nearest lower - value    34    =INDEX($B$2:$B$6, B9)
14 | Nearest higher - value   43    =INDEX($B$2:$B$6, B10)
15 | Interpolated value       39.4  =(B8-B11)/(B12-B11)*(B14-B13) + B13
```

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to get a weighted value and not the lowest value... See comments in the question

Comment: I used this command already, but I thought there might be more appropriate commands that are designed to find lower or higher values of a search criterion.

Comment: identifying lower value is *not* the solution - i think.**calculate weighted average** is - with all due respect sir.

Comment: To make clear: I need a command that shows me the lower and higher values, so that I can refer to this cells with my weighting formula. I also already used match, but this gives me the number of the row that is inappropriate for my calculation. You must imagine that his identification is a substep within a very complex real estate valuation. I thought there might be simple commands, but it shows to be more difficult than expected

Comment: Thanks for your time and useful help!! :)